# How do I prevent false flags in Background subtraction using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, background-subtraction

So, I am developing a hobby project where a camera is mounted on a bot, powered by `Raspberry Pi`. The bot moves around a room and does some processing based on the camera's response. I apologize, if this is not the right place to ask.

**Problem:-**

The camera attached to the bot will perform `Background subtraction` continuously.The bot will be moving simultaneously. In case the background algorithm detects an object in front of the bot, it'll stop the bot and do further processing with respect to the object. Here the working assumption is that the ground is of only one color and uniform to a great extent.

The algorithm works great under very controlled lighting conditions. The problem arises when there is slight lighting changes or when the ground has small patches/potholes/uneveness in it. The above scenarios generate false flags and as a result my bot stops. I want to know if there is any way to prevent these false flags with the help of any modifications in the following code ?

```
import picamera,cv2,time

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (512,512)
camera.awb_mode="fluorescent"
camera.iso = 800
camera.contrast=25
camera.brightness=64
camera.sharpness=100
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(512, 512))

first_time=0 # This flag is to capture the first frame as background image.
frame_buffer=0 # This flag is to change the background image every 30 frames.
counter=0
camera.start_preview()
sleep(1)

def imageSubtract(img):
    luv=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LUV)
    l,u,v=cv2.split(luv)
    return v


for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # Here first 10 frames are being rejected .
    if first_time==0:
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
        if frame_buffer<10:
           print("Frame rejected -",str(frame_buffer))
           frame_buffer+=1
           continue
        os.system("clear")
        refImg=frame.array
        refThresh=imageSubtract(refImg)
        first_time=1
        frame_buffer=0


    frame_buffer+=1
    cv2.imshow("Background",refImg)
    image = frame.array
    cv2.imshow("Foreground", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
    newThresh=imageSubtract(image)

    diff=cv2.absdiff(refThresh,newThresh) #Here the background image is sub from foreground

    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    diff = cv2.morphologyEx(diff, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    diff=cv2.dilate(diff,kernel,iterations = 2)

    _, thresholded = cv2.threshold(diff, 0 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY +cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    _, contours, _= cv2.findContours(thresholded,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    try:
       c=max(contours,key=cv2.contourArea)
       x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

       cv2.rectangle(thresholded,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(125,125,125),2)
       if cv2.contourArea(c)>300 and len(contours)<=3:
        if counter==0:
            print("Going to sleep for 0.1 second") # allowing the device to move ahead for 0.1 sec before processing the object
            time.sleep(0.1)
            counter=1
            continue
        else:
            print("Object found !")

       cv2.imshow("Threshold",thresholded)

       if frame_buffer%30==0:
          frame_buffer=0
          refImg=image
          refThresh=imageSubtract(refImg)
          os.system("clear")
          print("Refrence Image changed")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

**NOTE :-** The above algorithm used continuous capture mode of the PiCamera. Also, first 10 frames are rejected because I have noticed that the PiCamera takes some time to adjust the colors once it starts up. Another thing is that the background image is being changed every 30 frames because I wanted the background image to remain as close as possible to the foreground image. Since the room is quite big, there is going to be some local changes in the light/color of the ground between one corner of the room and the other. Hence, felt the need to update the background image after every 30 frames. The object needs to have an area greater than 300 for it to be detected. I have also given a delay of 0.1 sec  (`time.sleep(0.1)`) after the object  has been detected, because I wanted the object to enter the frame completely and  be right in the middle of the frame before the device stops.

**Some solutions that I had in mind was :-**

1. I thought of attaching few `IR sensors` at the base of the device. In case, an object is detected ( Real/False Flags), it'll check the output from `IR sensor` just to check if any object is being picked up by it as well. In case of shadows and patches, the IR response is going to be NULL, so the bot continues to move forward.
2. I thought of calculating the height of the detected object. If the height was above a certain threshold , then presence of object could have been confirmed. Otherwise it is a false flag. But, the camera is going to be facing down, which means the image is taken from top. So I don't think there is any way to ascertain the height of the object from it's top-down image.

Please suggest any alternative solutions. I want to make the above algorithm as perfect as possible because the entire working of the device depends upon the accuracy of the background subtraction algorithm.

Thank you for your help in advance !

EDIT 1-

Background Image - [Back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRzO8.jpg)
Foreground Image - [Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR7AJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Background subtraction works well when your camera is not moving and objects are moving in front of the camera. Your case is just the opposite and it will easily detect movement everywhere.

If your background is uniform, any edge detection filter may work better than your background subtraction.

Another alternative is using thresholding (see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html). I would suggest an adaptive threshold (Gaussian or mean) that will work better if the edges are darker than the center. Try different sizes of the neighbourhood and different values for the constant C.

Then you can erode/dilate as you already do and filter by size or position as you suggest. Adding more sensors to your robot is a good idea as well.

Comment: The ground is completely white, so the background doesn't change much except for occasional lighting variations. Won't edge detection suffer from the same problem ? It'll try to find edges for shadows/patchy areas along with objects.

Comment: If the shadows are not very sharp, the edge detection won't find them (you may need to adjust the parameters or do a threshold afterwards). For example, if an image is black in one side and white in the other, but there is a smooth transition, there will be no edges (edge detection should detect nothing), but background subtraction would see many differences if your robot turns.

Comment: I have added two sample images in the EDIT. Please check them. Will edge detection work for such images ?

Comment: Edge detection will find the vertical line as well. If you erode/dilate you can make it disappear, but the edges of the object may disappear as well. I added thresholding as another alternative (in that case, erode/dilate won't affect the object so much)